# How to Configure a Dual Monitor Upper/Lower Configuration With Lower as Primary

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have two setups where I use a one-monitor-above-the-other installation.  It is easy to set the top monitor as primary and mouse down to the lower monitor for use.  It is also easy to set the bottom monitor as primary, but then you must mouse down to get to the top monitor, which is not ideal.

Is it at all possible to have the lower monitor primary and mouse up to the secondary monitor?  If so...HOW??

I have the same issue with Ubuntu Mate and Xubuntu (22.04.1 for each).

Comment: go to your device settings, then click monitors/display/whatever, and you can adjust where the monitors are in relation to each other. You can put them on top/bottom, side-by-side, or some other configuration.

Comment: Alas, while that is true, if you configure a bottom/top setup with primary at the bottom, you have to mouse DOWN from the BOTTOM monitor to get to the TOP monitor.  That is the issue.

Comment: That usually means your device thinks the top monitor is on bottom, and the bottom one is on top.

Comment: Indeed.  I have tried to "fool" the process by switching the HDMI ports and by indicating that the top is the bottom, but when the primary goes to the bottom, and you apply the configuration, it reverts to "its preference."  Apparently, it is smarter than I.